# QGIS Trigger Defaults Immediately in Python Console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

In QGIS 3, I have points that I am setting up their latitude and longitude via Default values. The expression below is working to set them up, but the values only fill in on updates to their locations, so if the points are already in the project and I set up the default values, the Lat and Lon are both null unless I move them.

Is there a way for there to be an expression that would fill in the Lat and Lon without requiring an update to their locations?

```
for layer in layers:
    name=layer.name()
    if "Points" in name:
        lonField = layer.fields().indexFromName( 'Lon' )
        latField = layer.fields().indexFromName( 'Lat' )
        layer.setDefaultValueDefinition(lonField,QgsDefaultValue('$x',True))
        layer.setDefaultValueDefinition(latField,QgsDefaultValue('$y',True))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your script slightly so that, if there are any existing features in your layer, the "Lon" and "Lat" fields are populated with their `x` and `y` values first, then set the default value definitions.

```py
layers = [l for l in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() if l.type() == QgsMapLayerType.VectorLayer and
            l.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry]

for layer in layers:
    if "Points" in layer.name():
        lonField = layer.fields().indexFromName( 'Lon' )
        latField = layer.fields().indexFromName( 'Lat' )
        if layer.featureCount()>0:
            atts_map = {ft.id():{lonField: ft.geometry().asPoint().x(), latField: ft.geometry().asPoint().y()} for ft in layer.getFeatures()}
            layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(atts_map)
        layer.setDefaultValueDefinition(lonField,QgsDefaultValue('$x',True))
        layer.setDefaultValueDefinition(latField,QgsDefaultValue('$y',True))
```

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thank you!